# quanteda textstat_simil for text matching

Tags: r, text, matching, similarity, quanteda

Hello fellow text miners,

I am fairly new to the domain and I am trying to use quanteda's textstat_simil (R package) for assessing similarity between phrases. The steps are quite upfront - therefore I believe I m missing something obvious but I still cant get the feature selection working:

```
    #1 Create Corpus
myCorpus <- corpus(c("Anna, Maria, Luisa"))
checkWords <- c('Luisianna', 'anneta')
summary(myCorpus)

myDfm <- dfm(myCorpus)
myDfm # checking that features are there.
#removing stopwords & punctuation/ keep the stem 
myDfmNoStop <- dfm(myCorpus, remove = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE)

sim <- textstat_simil(myDfmNoStop , checkWords, method = "cosine", margin = "features")
```

Which returns the error:

"Error in textstat_simil.dfm(myDfm, checkWords, method = "cosine", margin = "features") : The features specified by 'selection' do not exist."

So, its not clear to me how can I specify the correct features/word of my coprus?

Needless to say - any feedback is more than welcome :)

Cheers,

George

Comment: The problem here is exactly what it says: you don't have the features "Luisianna" or "anneta" in your corpus or dfm. Therefore, you cannot look at the similarity of these non-existent terms to the three terms that do occur. Note as a reproducible example, this is not a very good one since the corpus consists of three one-word documents. You would not be able to construct a similarity matrix even for the included terms from such a dfm.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I did try with existent tokens as well getting the same response: > sim <- textstat_simil(myDfm, "Maria", method = "cosine", margin = "features")
Error in textstat_simil.dfm(myDfm, "Maria", method = "cosine", margin = "features") : 
  The features specified by 'selection' do not exist.  But as you said it really looks that this string similarity should not be used for individual words . Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myCorpus <- corpus(c(check = "Luisianna, anneta", 
                     target1 = "Anna, Maria, Luisa",
                     target2 = "Anna, anneta"))

myDfmNoStop <- dfm(myCorpus, remove = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE)

sim <- textstat_simil(myDfmNoStop , myDfmNoStop['check',], method = "cosine", margin = "documents")
```

Comment: - unless I'm being daft, this isn't reproducible now, you able to update it?